# TrueCrypt not resuming previously deferred tasks

Tags: windows-7, encryption, truecrypt

After using TrueCrypt to encrypt my laptop's internal drive, I decided to try encrypting my external backup drive as well. 37 hours later, I deferred the task — an action I've had no issue with before — and thought nothing of it. However, when trying to resume the interrupted process via ***System > Resume Inturrupted Process***, I'm greeted with a message box stating that there's nothing to resume.

However, when trying to create a new Volume, it reminds me that I have incomplete processes that need to be completed first. In addition, when I enter my password, I'm told that there aren't any related interrupted processes.

What should I do? I'd like to avoid formatting the drive, but there isn't any critical data contained within it.

Comment: Get your fix ?? I am in the same situation

Comment: @vcopola Sadly, no. I ended up formatting the drive a few days after posting this.

Comment: I believe its a bug in TC that it doesnt look for non-system drives:
http://sourceforge.net/p/veracrypt/tickets/42/?page=1 But I don't know any fix..

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was able to resume the encryption after running 'Tools\Volume Encryption Wizard'. 
Hope it helps someone, though I would NEVER use that 'defer' feature again.